# @ContentChildren and <ng-template> in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why does the first example using `ngFor` work (first and second dropdown), but the third doesn't (no options are shown in the dropdown)?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ft14ie?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fdropdown.component.html

```html
<h4>1. Does work</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <ng-template ngFor let-food [ngForOf]="foods">
      <mat-option [value]="food.value">
        {{ food.viewValue }}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<h4>2. Does work</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-food>
      <mat-option [value]="food.value">{{ food.viewValue }}</mat-option>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let value of foods; template: itemTemplate">
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<h4>3. Does not work</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-value>
      <mat-option [value]="value">{{ value }}</mat-option>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: 'Steak' }"
    >
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

`mat-select` of Angular Material uses `ContentChildren` to find `mat-option` (see [source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/16.0.0/src/material/select/select.ts#L1208)).
As far as I understand, my issue is related to the Angular issue [ContentChildren doesn't get children created with NgTemplateOutlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842). However, according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842#issuecomment-470167258) comment, I thought that my third example is equivalent to this example in the comment:

```html
<parent>
  <ng-template #tplWithChild>
     <child></child> <!-- this one DOES match when this template gets instantiated -->
   </ng-template>
   <child></child> <!-- this one DOES match as is written between parent tags -->
   <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tplWithChild"></ng-template>
</parent>
```

which should result in the child (in my example `mat-option`) to be found (in my example by `mat-select`). So why does my third example not work? Did I get something wrong?

And in all my confusion, why does the first and second example work? `mat-option` is also in a `ng-template` (of `ngFor`), but it is found.

Comment: In 2nd and 3rd you're using `<option>` instead of `<mat-option>`.

Comment: @TotallyNewb Thanks, the answer can sometimes be so simple. At least the second example is working then. However, the third still doesn't work after that change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with 3. is that `ng-container` still adds virtual layer: `mat-select` -> `ng-container` -> `mat-option`. So `mat-option` is no longer a direct content child of `mat-select`. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24858.

So you will have to create custom directive(s) that renders templates directly under `mat-select`. `NgTemplateOutlet` does not have any options to configure were it will render templates (for example via `ViewContainerRef`) but API does provide control over this.

Comment: I just realized that `ngTemplateOutlet` works if I use it on `ng-template` itself instead of `ng-container`, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szp29i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fdropdown.component.html
How does this change the render location?

Comment: Is `mat-select` passed as `ViewContainerRef` to `ngTemplateOutlet` if it is used on `ng-template`, i.e. the (surrounding) parent of the `ng-template` element? On the other hand, is `ng-container` passed as `ViewContainerRef` to `ngTemplateOutlet` if it is used on the `ng-container`, i.e. the `ng-container` element itself instead of its (surrounding) parent (i.e. `mat-select`)?

Comment: `ng-template` is the only true virtual element, it does not have any effect on component tree, and once you use directive on it it gets ViewContainerRef anchor and option appears in the right place. So this is clever workaround in the end.

Comment: How does `itemTemplate` influence its parent `mat-select`, when its passed to `ngTemplateOutlet` in another `mat-select`, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1tuqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fdropdown.component.html
I would have expected that both dropdowns look the same, but the second seems to have a broken option (white bar).

Comment: template captures original context, and mat-option depends on parent, it injects parent component, to make this work you will have to pass correct injector to ngTemplateOutlet I guess